# Нужно отследить каждое первое открытие приложения

Tags: ios, swift

В приложении есть нотификации с `firebase` откуда приходят `id` и `obj_type`. Это для того чтобы открыть раздел к примеру (новости, аналитику и тд) и передаем `id` новости чтобы открыть новость по `id`. Это все я обрабатываю в `AppDelegate` и от туда ставлю рутовский `ViewController`. Задача в том что если пользователь открыл нотификацию когда приложение было закрыто мне надо открывать `ViewController`. А если пользователь открыл нотификацию когда приложение уже было открытого то надо к примеру открыть `ViewController2`. Переходы у меня готовы, проблема с логикой, нужно как то отследить приложение открыось с "нуля" или уже было запущено, дабы осуществить соответсвующие переходы.

Что я попробовал:

```
    extension UIApplication {
    class func isFirstLaunch() -> Bool {
        if UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "hasBeenLaunchedBeforeFlag") {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "hasBeenLaunchedBeforeFlag")
            UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
            return true
        }
        return false
    }
}
```

Но к сожалению не помогло.

Answer (score 1):

Ваша идея правильная, вы просто допустили логическую ошибку:

```
    extension UIApplication {
class func isFirstLaunch() -> Bool {
    if UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "hasBeenLaunchedBeforeFlag") {
        return true
    }
    else {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "hasBeenLaunchedBeforeFlag")
        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
        return false
    }

}
```